# Removing label bit from caption is not working

Tags: captions, multicol, sciposter

I'm making a poster and I'm trying to remove the label bit -- "Figure xx:" -- from a `figure` caption, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162234/getting-rid-of-the-figure-1-bit.

The part of code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[portuges, brazil, english]{babel}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fancybullets}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}



\title{Title1}


\author[1]{name1}
\affil[1]{Insti1}


\leftlogo[1]{Instilogo}
\rightlogo[1]{lablogo}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Begin of Document


\begin{document}

\conference{Famous conference}



\maketitle

%%% Begin of Multicols-Enviroment
\begin{multicols}{3}

% Other irrelavent sections not shown here


\section*{Simulation Set-up}

\begin{itemize}
        \item Approach is validated using DNS simulations.
        
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = \columnwidth]{Simulation.png}
        \caption{Numerical Set-up}
        
        
        %\label{fig:enter-label}
    \end{figure}
    
    
        \item Pt 2
    
\end{itemize}

% Other irrelavent sections not shown here


\bibliographystyle{plain}\bibliography{poster}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

But surprisingly, I'm getting an error as follows:[image]

Can you please suggest what might have gone wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: LaTeX `figure` and `table` floats are *not allowed* in a `multicols` environment. Fore more information, see section 2.4, entitled "Floats inside a `multicols`
environment", of the user guide of the `multicol` package.

Comment: Excellent [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of the problem is that the [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package and its `multicols` environment do not permit the use of `table` and `figure` floats. Full-width `figure*` and `table*` *are* permitted; however, that's not relevant for you, is it?

In a deeper sense, though, the error lies with *you*: Since you have no intention of letting the graph float anywhere, you shouldn't be using a `figure` environment to begin with. (The feeble `[H]` placement specifier cannot help you out here.) Instead, what you should be doing is (a) employ a basic `center` environment (telling LaTeX to insert a bit of whitespace above and below the graph/caption combination) and (b) use `\captionof` instead of `\caption` to typeset the unnumbered caption.

One more remark about your code: You should use the option `width=\linewidth` instead of `width=\columnwidth`, since `\includegraphics` occurs within an `itemize` environment, which automatically reduces the value of `\linewidth` (but not that of `\columnwidth`).

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{sciposter} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

%%%\usepackage{epsfig} % is loaded automatically by 'graphixc'

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol} % for 'multicols' env.
\usepackage{graphicx,xurl} % use 'xurl', not 'url'
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[portuges, brazil, english]{babel}  
 
%%%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % <-- new
\usepackage{enumitem} % <-- new

\usepackage{caption} % provides '\captionof' macro
\captionsetup{labelformat=empty, 
              skip=0.5\baselineskip} % <--- new

\title{Title1}
\author[1]{Name1}
\affil[1]{Insti1}

\leftlogo{Instilogo}
\rightlogo{lablogo}
\conference{Famous conference}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{3}

% Other irrelevant sections not shown here

\section*{Simulation Set-up}

\begin{itemize}[left=0pt] % '[left=0pt]' is new

    \item Approach is validated using DNS simulations
        
    %%%\begin{figure}[H] % cannot use 'figure' float
    \begin{center}
        %%%\centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Simulation.png} % NOT '\columnwidth'
        %%%\caption{Numerical Set-up}
        \captionof{figure}{Numerical Setup}
        \label{fig:enter-label}
    %%%\end{figure}
    \end{center}

    \item Pt 2
    
    \item Pt 3
    
\end{itemize}

\lipsum[1-3] % filler text
    
% Other irrelevant sections not shown here

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Mico . So, to cite or reference a figure in the text, I can use the standard way of using \eqref{fig:enter-label}, right?

Comment: @saisaandeep - Use `\eqref` only to cross-reference equations by their associated numbers. For unnumbered figures and tables in a `sciposter` document, the basic `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism doesn't work as, by design, there are no numbers to note in a `\ref` statement. Please advise how you imagine a cross-reference to an unnumbered object should look like.